# Magento 2 - Readiness check fails on Check Component Dependency

Tags: magento2, extensions

I have Magento Community 2.2. installed on managed VPS (Hetzner).
I am trying to install component and before installation it starts "Readiness check".
All checks out except for:

```
Check Component Dependency

We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail

For additional assistance, see component dependency help .
```

I don't get any details on error.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I have followed instructions from here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/component-depend.html

- I have run command for file permissions described here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html
- I have tried with removing files `/var/.update_cronjob_status` and `/var/.setup_cronjob_status` and regenerating them starting Module Manager (probably previously known as Component manager)

POSSIBLE CAUSE
I was running installation of a module through composer and when asked for authorization (public and private keys) i have saved them in composer.json.
Since this is one of possible reasons listed in their documentation (changing of composer.json) all it says is to "edit composer.json" but it doesn't say how or what...
I have opened composer.json but I didn't find any keys there...

---

### UPDATE

I have 2 locations for file `composer.json`:

- `\public_html\composer.json`
- `\public_html\var\composer.json`

Also have 2 locations for file `auth.json`:

- `\public_html\composer_home\auth.json`
- `\.composer\auth.json`

I appreciate help with this :)

---

**Sorry for updates, I am slowly remembering everything I did :)**

**I have tried to install this:** - Iazel_RegenProductUrl -  https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls

**I have installed this:** - OlegKoval_RegenerateUrlRewrites - https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

While installing through SSH I had some memory problems and got `Killed` in process.
I found a way to run commands again and installed 1 module listed above.

Module wasn't working as expected so I have tried to install one from Magento Marketplace https://marketplace.magento.com/itcolony-seooverwrite.html. This is where I got error with "Readiness check" and started to investigate on possible causes and solutions.

After that I checked `composer.json` and saw both modules (Iazel_RegenProductUrl and OlegKoval_RegenerateUrlRewrites) are listed in `require:` section so I deleted the line where `Iazel_RegenProductUrl` because I thought it caused problems (since install got killed).

Here it my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.7",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.7",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "olegkoval/magento2-regenerate-url-rewrites": "^1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.3.8",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.2.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For this problem you have to delete these lines in Composer.json, and it is solved:

```
"require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~1.0.0",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "~2.3.14",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1"
    },
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Solved this issue.

You need to update php memory limits in `.htaccess` and `.user.ini` files in Magento root directory from 765MB to 2G as they override system php limits.

Answer (score 1):

This is according to the documentation.

Typically, component dependency conflicts result from someone manually editing the Magento 2 `composer.json` file. It can also be caused by `third-party modules` that depend on earlier Magento components than the ones you have installed. Meaning you have to check the `composer.json` of the component you are trying to install and determine from its `require` modules which dependency might be the cause of the issue.

Lastly, authentication keys are saved in `auth.json` file, not inside `composer.json`. try to check it you should see your keys there.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question with file locations - it seems I have double files (is that normal?). I am not sure what am I supposed to do with `composer.json` - should I remove lines where suspicious modules are mentioned?

Comment: Yeah that's normal , but you should only work with those from your Magento root directory, \public_html\composer.json and \public_html\auth.json

Comment: which module are you trying to install when you get the error? probably check from there, open it check its composer.json and look for dependencies that has an old version change it to the latest version and it should work

Comment: I have installed this: https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites and have tried to install this: https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls

Comment: In this `https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls` module's composer.json, try to remove everything in require, like leave it as `"require": {
    },`

Comment: the nrun again your installation

Comment: The problem is that I don't have that module in `/app/code/...` :( Can I simply copy module there and try again? Maybe it is looking for it's composer.json and cannot find it?..

Comment: ah I see. because it comes from marketplace

Comment: I mean the one you tried and got the error since the first two were not working well

Comment: I think it's much better if you can find its package file like from git or from anywhere. hopefully they are available , or the best thing contact their support and inform them about the error you got when trying to install their package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91778/discussion-between-oktarin-and-magefms).

Answer (score 1):

`auth.json`is located at `~/.composer/auth.json`